# Simple Gnuradio TX/RX loopback example/tutorial

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I'm looking for some sort of simple and a beginner level instructions on how to build TX/RX loopback flowgraph using GnuRadio software and B200 USRP with an attenuator FW -10 + 10dB.
Kindly, help me with any available examples/resources you have.

Update:
What I meant by a loopback here is a simple flowgraph that has both: a transmitter and receiver, to transmit a signal and receive it by connecting the TR port to the RX on the USRP device.

Comment: Hi Hadad, welcome to Amateur Radio SE. Your question is very broad. Please elaborate, what research have you already done, what have you already found?

Comment: Can we see the flowgraph?

Comment: @mike65535, That's what I'm looking for!

Comment: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Simulation_example:_Narrowband_FM_transceiver is pretty close.